# Deploying gridsome app to apache 2 server

Tags: apache, web-deployment, static-site, gridsome

I have a Static Site written with Gridsome that I would like to deploy to my LAMP server running Apache 2.4. Looking on line I have tried several solutions including a 200.html in the directory and adding a .htacces file in the directory with contents -

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

But site does not load correctly(no css, js) and all Product pages come back 404 Not Found. I see in console that css and js files are all coming back 404 codes.
Here are Apache logs:

```
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /furniture/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3894 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/css/0.styles.be923654.css HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/js/app.f3ee1f73.js HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/js/page--src-pages-index-vue.aca59de8.js HTTP/1.1" 404 491 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/js/app.f3ee1f73.js HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/js/page--src-pages-index-vue.aca59de8.js HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/static/favicon.ac8d93a.5667663fadd9573f98b6a9c36dd676aa.png HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/js/page--node-modules-gridsome-app-pages-404-vue.0ed1ba31.js HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/js/page--src-pages-about-vue.de5a1202.js HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:07 -0500] "GET /assets/js/page--src-templates-product-vue.05ad6ad3.js HTTP/1.1" 404 491 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
```

And when I try to go to one of the Product Pages -

```
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:52 -0500] "GET /products/strul-rug/ HTTP/1.1" 404 491 "http://172.16.178.9/furniture/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
172.16.178.62 - - [16/Jan/2020:13:24:52 -0500] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 490 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0"
```

**Update**: I see the problem. When looking at dev console network all the URI requests are:

```
Request URL:http://172.16.178.9/assets/css/0.styles.be923654.css
Request Method:GET
```

They should be

```
http://172.16.178.9/furniture/some/asset/to/get
```

How can one rectify this? thanks..

Answer (score 0):

If it's just a html file, there is no reason that apache would not be able to serve it, but as you have modified .htaccess make sure that apache .conf file allows you to override to directory level htaccess files.
I mean does your server's conf allow you to oberride the htaccess? there should be a line similar to following in your main apache conf file (located by default at /etc/apache2/apache2.conf):

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In general I am not sure why you even need htaccess file if all you are trying to serve are static HTML and CSS,JS files.

Comment: Have you ran gridsome build? I don't see any html files on your repo! Also there was error in my answer, it should be allow override all, I have updated the answer make sure it's there in server conf if you wish to use htaccess.

Comment: Yes. I deployed to netlify and the website renders fine. I then ran gridsome build and ftp'd the /dist folder up to my LAMP server and that's when I have issues with it rendering.

Comment: Can you upload the generated dist directory to github? There is nothing that should be blocking apache server from serving basic html, js and css files by default. (In fact you don't need any htaccess by default to serve those formats!)

Comment: I made made directory directive /var/www/furniture. Is that ok? I have other sites on apache in /var/www/.

Comment: Yes give me a minute. I need to go over to my home computer and do a build and push it.

Comment: Depending on how your server is configured, you will need to create VirtualHost! Follow this link: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html    You can also find some good resource of how to setup virtual host by searching on google and youtube, give it a shot!

Comment: Your github link is no longer available, please post it again

Comment: I dont think the Virtual Host applies to my setup. It's just for internal use and no dns for the sites is enabled. If you want to visit a hosted site just hit 172.16.xxx.xxx/mysite or 172.16.xxx.xxx/anothersite.

Comment: Yup, than it does not matter.

Comment: I will try to rebuild it, and see if my output differs, the problem is with the files not the server.

Comment: Ok I think I see problem. All the request url headers are missing the subdirectory name /furniture. see here- Request URL:http://172.16.178.9/assets/css/0.styles.be923654.css
Any idea how to rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out real simple. I needed to add *pathPrefix* property to gridsome.config.js to make build include /furniture in URI's.

```
// gridsome.config.js
module.exports = {
  siteName: "Ecommerce & Gridsome",
  pathPrefix: "/furniture",
  templates: {
    Product: "/products/:title" // Set route for allProduct node's
  }
};
```